# Filtering a dataframe from information in another dataframe using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a dataframe that is below.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Chromosome', 'Start','End'],
     data=[
           ['chr1', 2000, 3000],
           ['chr1', 500, 1500],
           ['chr3', 3000, 4000],
           ['chr5', 4000, 5000],
           ['chr17', 9000, 10000],
           ['chr19', 1500, 2500]
           ])
```

I have a probe dataframe as below.

```
probes = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Probe', 'Chrom','Position'],
     data=[
           ['CG999', 'chr1', 2500],
           ['CG000', 'chr19, 2000],
           ])
```

I want to filter df for rows which contains a probes chromosome and which has the probes position between it's Start and End numbers, then add the probes name to a new column/field in df. The desired output is below:

```
    Probe    Chrom    Start    End
0   CG999    chr1     2000     3000
5   CG000    chr19    1500     2500
```

My attempt below works but doesn't place the probe name into a Probe column and is reliant on looping probes data. There must be a more efficient way of doing this.

```
all_indexes = []

# fake2.tsv is the aforementioned probes dataframe
with open('fake2.tsv') as f:
    for x in f:
        probe, chrom, pos = x.rstrip("\n").split("\t")
        row = df[(df['Chromosome'] == chrom) & ((int(pos) > df['Start']) & (int(pos) < df['End']))]
        all_indexes.append(t.index.tolist())

all_t = [y for x in all_t for y in x]
df.iloc[all_indexes]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.merge(probes, left_on='Chromosome', right_on='Chrom').query('Start < Position < End')
```

Output:

```
  Chromosome  Start   End  Probe  Chrom  Position
0       chr1   2000  3000  CG999   chr1      2500
2      chr19   1500  2500  CG000  chr19      2000
```

Answer (score 1):

I just encountered the same problem, and apparently there is no built-in solution in pandas. However you may use of the solutions on following threads:

- [Best way to join/merge by range in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367672/best-way-to-join-merge-by-range-in-pandas)
- [how to perform an inner or outer join of DataFrames with Pandas on
  non-simplistic criterion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15581829/how-to-perform-an-inner-or-outer-join-of-dataframes-with-pandas-on-non-simplisti)